# GKGridGraph find path not working

Tags: objective-c, gameplay-kit

I'm trying to make a turn based game, and each enemy should find a path to player node. I'm using gameplaykit's pathfinding, and every time enemy has to make a turn, I make sure to remove other enemies from that GKGridGraph (so that enemy won't walk on one another) and latter I add that same nodes.

```
NSMutableArray <GKGridGraphNode *> *walls = [NSMutableArray array];

for(SKNode *mapNode in enemies)
  {
    for(SKNode *node in mapNode.children)
      {
        if((node.position.x != enemy.position.x)||(node.position.y != enemy.position.y))
          {
            GKGridGraphNode *graphNode = [_NewGraph nodeAtGridPosition:
            (vector_int2){(node.position.x-300)/70, (node.position.y-180)/70}];
            [walls addObject:graphNode];
          }
        }
      }
[_NewGraph removeNodes:walls];

GKGridGraphNode* GKenemyNode = [_NewGraph nodeAtGridPosition:(vector_int2)
                         {(enemy.position.x-300)/70, (enemy.position.y-180)/70}];

GKGridGraphNode* GKplayerNode = [_NewGraph nodeAtGridPosition:(vector_int2)
                        {(player.position.x-300)/70,(player.position.y-180)/70}];
NSArray<GKGridGraphNode *> *path = [_NewGraph findPathFromNode:GKenemyNode toNode:GKplayerNode];
[_NewGraph addNodes:walls];
```

If I comment out lines removeNodes and addNodes everything works fine.

EDIT: Would it be a good idea to every time create new class object that could return generated GKGridGraph, instead of reasigning the same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so I found the answer and would like to share with all of you !
After removing nodes I did this (no need to add nodes as I did):

```
for(GKGridGraphNode *node in walls)
{
  [NewGraph connectNodeToAdjacentNodes:node];
}

NewGraph = nil;
```

GoodLuck !